# Why observable does not get subscribed

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

I have following observable, that validate changes on the model.

The code snippet looks as follow:

```
  const oSaveCancelStateOb = this.determineSaveCancelStateOb(oTableItemChanges, oSaveCancelStateModelOb);
  oSaveCancelStateOb.subscribe(function (oOb) {
    console.log("Subscribe 1");
  });

  oDelBtnOb
    .switchMapTo(oSaveCancelStateOb)
    .subscribe(function (oOb) {
      console.log("Subscribe 2");
    });
```

The implementation of `determineSaveCancelStateOb` looks as follow:

```
determineSaveCancelStateOb: function (oInspectionServiceOb, oSaveCancelStateModelOb) {
  return oInspectionServiceOb
    .map(function (bState) {
      return bState ? {bSave: true, bCancel: true} : {bSave: false, bCancel: false};
    })
    .switchMap(function (oState) {
      return oSaveCancelStateModelOb
        .map(function (oModel) {
          return {oModel: oModel, oState: oState};
        })
    });
},
```

The `oSaveCancelStateOb` verify, if somethings has changed on the model, it is a cold observable.

The second observable `oDelBtnOb` is a hot observable, it listen on the mouse button click.

My expectation is, when I clicked on the button, it should show me on the console:

```
Subscribe 1
Subscribe 2
```

But I've got only

```
Subscribe 2
```

Why the first observable does not get subscribed?

**Update**

Take a look to the following code snippet:

```
//Create an observable that emits a value every second
const sample1$ = Rx.Observable.of(true);
sample1$.subscribe(val => console.log(val))
//Create an observable that emits every time document is clicked
const sample2$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'click');

sample2$.switchMapTo(sample1$).subscribe(val => console.log(val))
```

When I click on the document, I am expecting the `true` will output twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i understand the code your expectation is incorrect. In your last example the following will happen:

1. after loading the code the subscription on `sample1$` will execute and process all values in the stream and for each value available emit it to the console. After that the `sample1$` subscription completes.
2. upon clicking on the document a `switchMapTo` is done to a new `sample1$` stream, its values (only `true`) are emitted and sent to the console, after which this observable completes.

Comment: The second point that you mentioned, the first subscribe will not executed again when clicking on the document?

Comment: @zero_coding correct, the first subscription has completed already by the time that you click on the document